# View all created JS objects in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do I view all JS objects that I created in chrome? I know if I type window into the console, I will see everything, but where is the tab that is filled with all my things?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like [Chrome Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints). Basically, in the developer tools, you will go to 'sources', click the file you are wanting to debug, and set a breakpoint on the line in the file that you want to see your active variables. You do this by simply clicking on the line number. When you reload, the browser will pause execution on this line and you will be able to see all the information you are looking for.